# Does an OP_RETURN script always need another output within the transaction?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, protocol, script, op-return

I was reading this:
[Explanation of what an OP_RETURN transaction looks like](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29554/explanation-of-what-an-op-return-transaction-looks-like)
and I wondered if the second output "value" : 0.00200000, was at all necessary. Can I just have a OP_RETURN with a 0 output in the transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to retain any change, yes you will need two outputs to return unspent Bitcoin to yourself. If you are spending for example a 0.0001 BTC output, 0.0001 to fees, then a single 0 BTC `OP_RETURN` output would be valid.

Comment: This is for a standard transaction, meaning testnet doesn't have these limitations