# Why does this coinbase transaction have two op_return outputs?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, op-return

I've been looking at coinbase transactions for fun and I came across one with two op_return outputs..

Does anyone know what the second one is?

Also, I understand the first op_return is used to [embed the merkleroot](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74162/op-return-in-a-coinbase-transaction) of the witness tree for segwit transactions in the block.

However, I've also seen coinbase transactions with multiple op_returns such as [this one.](https://blockstream.info/block/0000000000000000000684b22621c3c472b7ada29eb21ea80c1473e093370017)  Is there a specific purpose for that 2nd op_return or is the miner simply using it for their own purpose?

Answer (score 9):

Coinbase transactions have some special rules not shared by other transactions:

- only one per block
- must be the first transaction in the block
- must have OP_RETURN output with witness commitment if block includes segwit transactions
- must have only one input
- the input must have the "coinbase" field instead of a scriptSig

The "coinbase" field is where miners put the `extranonce`, commit to a specific blockheight (see [BIP-34](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0034.mediawiki)), and mark blocks to be found by them. Although, miners often collect the block reward in a single output, beside the rules for the witness commitment, **the Coinbase transaction has no special restrictions on other outputs**. In fact, some mining pools used to pay out mining rewards directly from the Coinbase, see e.g. [the Coinbase of 133,471 mined by Eligius creating 919 outputs](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/f36222943ad100899acbd8300f943ee2c127babef879d8a3c0696c0d914e04ca). **As such, the second `OP_RETURN` output could be anything the miner wants.**