# Why does IsCoinBase() check if there is exactly one input?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, transaction-verification, coinbase-transaction

In the Bitcoin Core source code there is a [function](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/primitives/transaction.h#L335) to check if a given transaction is a coinbase or not:

```
    bool IsCoinBase() const
    {
        return (vin.size() == 1 && vin[0].prevout.IsNull());
    }
```

Does it really need to check if `vin.size()` is equal to 1? Isn't `vin[0].prevout.IsNull()` a sufficient condition for a transaction to be a coinbase?
Is there any situation that the later condition is true but we have more than one input?

The only reason I can guess is to avoid run-time error when `vin` is empty (so there is no `vin[0]`).

Comment: Hi Amir, I edited the title of this topic because the previous felt a bit vague. I tried to capture the main idea of your question. Please feel free to revert or otherwise edit it if this doesn't align with what you wanted to express.

Comment: @Murch Hi Murch, thanks for your edit. It's now really better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A coinbase transaction is not allowed to have any other inputs, hence this check. Furthermore, because this check is part of consensus code, it is the definition for a coinbase transaction, so this ends up being a bit circular - the function says that a coinbase transaction must only have one input, and it checks that.

Answer (score 0):

A coinbase transaction uses an input to store metadata. Some types of metadata are the block height and extra nonce. See:

- [BIP 34: Block v2, Height in Coinbase](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0034.mediawiki)
- [Bitcoin Wiki: Transaction - Generation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Generation)
- [Bitcoin Stack Exchange: Why does this coinbase transaction have two op_return outputs?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90127/why-does-this-coinbase-transaction-have-two-op-return-outputs/90156#90156)